# Error With building CEF in Windows

Tags: c, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to build CEF branch 1180 on windows with Visual Studio 2010, but i get this problem when building for the first time.

```
Error   12  error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 2.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   151 6 generate_supplemental_dependency
Error   17  error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   151 6 webcore_bindings_sources
Error   1763    error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Chromium\home\src\cef\Debug\lib\webkit.lib' C:\Chromium\home\src\cef\LINK   libcef
Error   1766    error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Chromium\home\src\cef\Debug\lib\libcef.lib' C:\Chromium\home\src\cef\LINK   cef_unittests
Error   1767    error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Chromium\home\src\cef\Debug\lib\libcef.lib' C:\Chromium\home\src\cef\LINK   cefclient
Error   151 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\XPathGrammar.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   154 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\XMLNSNames.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   163 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\XMLNames.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx   webcore_bindings
Error   142 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\XLinkNames.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   155 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\WebKitFontFamilyNames.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   147 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\V8SVGElementWrapperFactory.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   140 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\V8HTMLElementWrapperFactory.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   156 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\UserAgentStyleSheetsData.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   146 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\SVGNames.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx   webcore_bindings
Error   148 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\SVGElementFactory.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   143 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\MathMLNames.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   153 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\MathMLElementFactory.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   144 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\HTMLNames.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   157 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\HTMLEntityTable.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   150 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\HTMLElementFactory.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   141 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\ExceptionCodeDescription.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   152 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\EventFactory.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   139 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\CSSValueKeywords.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   145 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\CSSPropertyNames.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   162 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\CSSGrammar.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   149 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\ColorData.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx  webcore_bindings
Error   164 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\CalendarPicker.cpp': No such file or directory C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   175 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources19.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   174 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources18.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   160 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources17.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   176 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources16.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   170 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources15.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   172 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources14.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   171 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources13.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   167 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources12.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   165 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources11.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   179 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources10.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   166 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources09.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   177 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources08.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   168 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources07.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   158 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources06.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   161 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources05.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   178 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources04.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   169 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources03.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   159 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources02.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
Error   173 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../../../../..\build\..\cef\Debug\\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\V8DerivedSources01.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\Chromium\home\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\WebCore.gyp\c1xx webcore_bindings
```

i dont know how to solve this, my directory structure is as follow:

i have Chromium version 21.0.1180.18 in C:\Chromium\home\src and i have CEF1 branch 1180 in C:\Chromium\home\src\cef and i have set the environment variable GYP_MSVS_VERSION to 2010 as was explained in the build guide of CEF.

Building the project in the command line went without problems, but when i build i VS2010 i get the problem above.

Can i someone help resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be environmental variables issues.
there could be some space in the folder where cef code is checked out. Try to keep in the folder where there are no spaces in the folder name.